# OleDbConnection not reading full records from excel C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have excel file , it contains 300000 records.
 I read data from excel file and convert it to datatable using following code.

This code sometimes read all records 300000 record and sometime 238000.

```
using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=FilePath;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HRD=YES; IMEX=1;'"))
{
    excel_con.Open();
    string sheet1 = "";
    sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

    DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();
    using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
    {
        oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
    }
    excel_con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Look at row 238,000 and see if something is odd about it.  Do you have any exceptions?

Comment: No, exception occurred.

Comment: At row 238,000 , data against some columns is empty.

Comment: Is there any timeout on OleDbConnection  and OleDbDataAdapter  ?